# Create DDLs and write to separate files with table name as file name

Tags: python

I have a use case where I have a file which has multiple create statements like below:

```
Create table schema1.table1(
col1 char(1) NOT NULL,
col2 char(2) NOT NULL,
col3 char(3) NOT NULL)
in DBNAME.TABLEPREFIX
Partition by size every 16g;
Comment on Column schema1.table1.col1 is 'text1'
Comment on Column schema1.table1.col2 is 'text2'
Comment on Column schema1.table1.col3 is 'text3'

---------

Create table schema1.table2(
col1 char(1) NOT NULL,
col2 char(2) NOT NULL,
col3 char(3) NOT NULL)
in DBNAME.TABLEPREFIX
Partition by size every 16g;
Comment on Column schema1.table2.col1 is 'text1'
Comment on Column schema1.table2.col2 is 'text2'
Comment on Column schema1.table2.col3 is 'text3'
```

I want to split these Create statements using Python and write to separate files with table name as filename (table1.sql). However, I want the create statement to look like below where I extract the comment from the input file and add it to the DDL where I declare the column name. How do I achieve this using Python?

I have the code to split the create statement but I don't know how to extract the column and match it with the input comments and modify it like below:

```sql
Create table schema1.table1(
col1 char(1) NOT NULL COMMENT $$col1-text1$$,
col2 char(2) NOT NULL COMMENT $$col2-text2$$,
col3 char(3) NOT NULL COMMENT $$col3-text3$$);
```

Sample code:

```
import re

def split_create(input_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        sql_script = file.read()

    create_statements = re.split(r'\bcreate\b', sql_script, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    
    for statement in create_statements[1:]:
        table_name_match = re.search(r'\btable\b\s+\w+\.(\w+)', statement)

        if table_name_match:
            table_name = table_name_match.group(1)
            
            output_path = f"path\\{table_name}.sql"
            with open(output_file, 'w') as output_file:
                output_path.write(f"CREATE OR REPLACE {statement};\n")
            print(f"Create statement saved {output_path.name}")

input_file = f"path\\sample.txt"

split_create(input_file)
```

How can I modify or what to add to the above script to get the desired output?